# insert hyperlink for more that 1000 entries in excel

Tags: excel, hyperlink

i habe many entries in excell ( more than 3000 ).
actually their are hyperlink but just like a text. i need to convert them in excel hyperlink but dont know how do to that with thousends of entries. please help.

```
\\192.162.0.2\public
\\192.162.0.2\public\Big-PC.log
\\192.162.0.2\public\InstantReview-ExperimentalHive.reg
\\192.162.0.2\public\InstantReview.reg
\\192.168.0.2\public\Invitation-BLUB.ir
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the formula & drag;

```
=HYPERLINK(A1, A1)
```

Edit;

I put `=HYPERLINK(B3, B3)` in the *formula bar* and hit enter (to get the colour effects that don't seem to appear otherwise for some reason) then dragged down;

[image]

Comment: but your solution makes fix hyperlinks. its will be always just one for all entries.

Comment: I get no file:// prefix in xl 2k10; drag the formula down and it will fill for A2,3,4,...

Comment: it is always the same link and text from following entry

Comment: if the 1st link is in cell **B2** put `=HYPERLINK(B2, B2)` next to it in cell **C2**, then drag C2 vertically downwards from the lower right corner of the selection box

Comment: iam doing the same, but all linknames will be as following entry and they all ahave same url from followinf entry again.

Comment: are the links all in the same column? if not whats the layout?

Comment: \\192.162.0.2\public   --> B3
\\192.162.0.2\public\Big-PC.log  --> B4
\\192.162.0.2\public\InstantReview-ExperimentalHive.reg  --> B5

Comment: if the links are all the same, make sure to calculate the sheet. Shift+F9

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you a generic answer to these sorts of problems.

1. start Macro recording
2. convert the first item (convert your
   fisrt text cell to hyperlink)
3. stop Macro recording
4. open the recorded macro and copy the
   code snippet that does the job
5. write a function (using the code snippet) that iterates over
   all your items and does the job

(If you have further problems with one specific step, then that should be considered as a new question, I guess)